# Approvals at task level in Azure Devops YAML pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, task

Recently, I have started playing a bit with pipelines in Azure DevOps. However, would like to understand the Approval process. Can approvals be added only at the stage level or can it be added further down like job or task level?

Any help or documents explaining it would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, does Daniel's answer can answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

Approvals can be set up at the stage level (as you've discovered) via checks and approvals on the environment.

They can also be set up *between* jobs with a [manual validation task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/manual-validation?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml), which runs in a "server" (i.e. agentless) job.

Ex:

```
jobs:
  - job: waitForValidation
    displayName: Wait for external validation
    pool: server
    timeoutInMinutes: 4320 # job times out in 3 days
    steps:
    - task: ManualValidation@0
      timeoutInMinutes: 1440 # task times out in 1 day
      inputs:
        notifyUsers: |
          test@test.com
          example@example.com
        instructions: 'Please validate the build configuration and resume'
        onTimeout: 'resume'
```

They cannot be set between tasks within a job.